# A model of sailsjs does not make mocha or jest terminate

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocha.js, sequelize.js, sails.js

I work on a web API build using sailsjs and sequelize as an ORM instead of Waterline.
I start write a test for the API using mocha, chai and chaijs. I need to remove all data which created during the test after all tests ends, but when I use a model to drop the data in the `after` hook (`afterAll` in jest), the test runner does not terminate.

Here is the code:

```
// set environement to test, to use test configuration
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'

const sails = require('sails');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

let server;

// Before running any tests...
before(function(done) {
  const wait = 10000;
  console.log(`wait ${wait / 1000}sec. until sails complete loads...`);

  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift, even if you have a bunch of assets.
  this.timeout(wait);

  sails.lift({
    // Your Sails app's configuration files will be loaded automatically,
    // but you can also specify any other special overrides here for testing purposes.

    // For example, we might want to skip the Grunt hook,
    // and disable all logs except errors and warnings:
    // hooks: { grunt: false },
    hooks: {
      "blueprints": false,
      "orm": false,
      "pubsub": false,
      "grunt" : false
    },
    log: { level: 'warn' },

  }, function(err) {
    if (err) return done(err);

    server = sails.hooks.http.app;

    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    // (for example, you might want to create some records in the database)

    return done();
  });
});

after(async function() {
    const wait = 10000; // 10 seconds
    this.timeout(wait);

    try {
        await sails.models.user.destroy({
            where: {},
            force: true
          });
      } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }

    return sails.lower();
  });

describe('#Auth Controller - Register', () => {
  it('/signup has no GET method', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
      .get('/auth/signup')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        if (err) done(err);

        expect(res).to.has.property('status');
        expect(res.status).to.equal(404);
        done();
     });
  });

  it('/signup response code expected to not equal "200", when request body is empty', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        if (err) done(err);

        expect(res).to.has.property('status');
        expect(res.status).to.not.equal(200);
        done();
     });
  });

  it('/signup expected to respond with error, when request body is empty', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        if (err) done(err);

        expect(res.body).to.has.property('status');
        expect(res.body.status).to.equal('error');
        done();
     });
  });
});
```

I tried jest to run the test and changed the required changes in before and after. and here is the afterAll hook:

```
afterAll(async function() {
    try {
      await sails.models.user.destroy({
          where: {},
          force: true
        });
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }

    return sails.lower();
});
```

jest does not terminate too. and it prints it the log

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue
e.
```

I used `--detectOpenHandles` option with jest but nothing happened.
So I tried to remove the DB call and changed it with another promise like the following, and it worked as expected, and mocha (and jest) terminated.

```
after(async function() {
    const wait = 10000; // 10 seconds
    this.timeout(wait);

    await new Promise(resolve => {
      const fn = function timeoutCb() {
        console.log('\n\nfrom time out\n\n');
        resolve();
      };

      setTimeout(fn, 0)
    });

    return sails.lower();
  });
```

Then to make sure that sailsjs lower successfully, I add a callback function to it.

```
after(async function() {
    const wait = 10000; // 10 seconds
    this.timeout(wait);

    try {
        await sails.models.user.destroy({
            where: {},
            force: true
          });
      } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }

    const cb = (err) => {
        if (err) console.err('sails does not exit:\n', err);
        else console.log('tests are done.');
      };

    return sails.lower(cb);
});
```

When test ends, `tests are done.` prints in the terminal, and when I use jest it prints

```
●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "tests are done.".
```

My environment and tools versions:

```
OS: (GNU/Linux) fedora 30
node: 10.16.1
npm: 6.11.3
sailsjs: 1.1.0
sails-hook-sequelize: 1.2.0
sequelize: 4.38.0
mocha: 6.2.0
jest: 24.9.0
chai: 4.2.0
chai-http: 4.3.0
```

Comment: Same problem here. I used wtfnode node package and found that even after sails.lower(), sails still have open sockets.